# Meaning of "Three cheers, indeed; but there was more to come, an unguessed epilogue, an encore played to a tragic audience"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> Three cheers, indeed; but there was more to come, an unguessed epilogue, an encore played to a tragic audience.

This text is from Good-Bye Mr. Chips (2nd Chapter, last sentence).

As Grammar Translation method is followed, it is very difficult to understand it with that method. Because the denotative sense of the sentence is quite nonsensical in our language, particularly the last part of the sentence (an encore played to a tragic audience). So, is it possible to rewrite the same sentence in a simple and easily understandable way?

Comment: _Tragic audience_ is a rather odd expression - it was the encore that was tragic, not the 'audience'. There was a sad episode in Mr. Chips' past that hardly anyone knew about. _There was an epilogue to the story that no-one could have guessed, a sad encore to the 'play'._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Indeed, there were three cheers, as though the drama were over. But in fact there was more to come. You might say there was an epilogue that no one could have guessed, or an encore performance, which was played for a sad audience.

As Kate wrote, "tragic audience" is problematic. It's probably a transposition from the tragic nature of the play onto the people who watched it ([metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy)). I've simplified it to be about the audience, though, who would no doubt be sad to see a tragic play.

If you still find this gloss confusing, please let me know something specific and I can update this answer.

Comment: Could it not be a transferred epithet?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's what I mean by transposition. "Synecdoche" is the wrong word. I always get it mixed up with metonymy.

Comment: You and me both.